# Retrieve Spark DataFrame from Scala Either

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a DataFrame output from Scala coming into Either. I am looking to retrieve the Spark DataFrame out from it.

I have an Azure SQL connection in databricks that I used scala to connect. I can connect to the database and can output the query. It gives me a Spark DataFrame in the below Scala format which I am new to, can someone help me retrieve it so I can use save it as a hive table

Result of my scala code:

```
outputData: Either[org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame,Boolean] = Left([Product: string, OrderNumber: string ... 27 more fields])
```

`outputData` is the Spark DataFrame that contains :

`Product: string, OrderNumber: string ... 27 more fields..`

I am not sure how to get the DF from `Either`.

Comment: What do you want to happen when there is no dataframe in the result? (i.e. when the return value is a boolean instead of dataframe).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have a function that is returning Either as below.

```scala
def abc(): Either[DataFrame, Boolean] = {...}
```

To get DataFrame, you just need to apply `get` function as below

```scala
abc.left.get
```

It will give you the DataFrame.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing too much about the exact way you retrieve your `DataFrame` and how/why you assign the right value, let me write a toy function that returns a `DataFrame` in case if the input is even, otherwise returns `Right(false)`:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame

def readDfIfEven(n: Int): Either[DataFrame, Boolean] = {
  if (n % 2 == 0) {
    val df = spark.read.format("json").load("/databricks-datasets/definitive-guide/data/flight-data/json/2015-summary.json")
    Left(df)
  } else {
    Right(false)
  }
}
```

Now to answer your question:

What I would do in this case, is to apply pattern matching to get the `DataFrame`:

```scala
readDfIfEven(2) match {
  case Left(df: DataFrame) => df.show() // note that type annotation here is just for illustration
  case Right(status) => println($"Could not get DataFrame with status ${status}")
}
```

Comment: I am using scala to connect Azure SQL into databricks using the following code
[link](https://docs.databricks.com/data/data-sources/sql-databases-azure.html#pushdown-query-to-azure-sql-database-or-sql-server)
Added: val outputData = sqlContext.sqlDBQuery(config) command that returns the output: outputData: Either[org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame,Boolean] = Left([Product: string, OrderNumber: string ... 27 more fields])
I am just using Scala for this connection and just looking to retreive DataFrame so I can do manipulation in PySpark

Comment: your answer worked too, big thanks to explaining what an Either and how it works